# DCB Structure Configurability for USB HID Device

Tags: visual-c++, usb, hid

I am designing an interfacing layer for a USB HID device that I have yet to see full documentation for. I've read through the documentation on the DCB structure multiple times and have a fundamental question about the whole DCB configuration.

Is the DCB config supposed to be defined by the software client, or are the correct values completely dependent on the design of the HID device. IE - if I set the stop bits, parity, or baud rate to a value other than what is designed into the USB device, will it work? Or is this something highly dependent on the device; like do some devices allow themselves to be configured while others don't?

I'm basically trying to figure out how much time I should spend figuring out this DCB stuff. The device does not come with any software library, just a protocol definition for communications.

Comment: What type of device are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The DCB is designed for use with serial communication ports like RS-232 & RS-485. It must be configured by the software client so that the basic parameters correspond to what the external device uses, not what the USB uses. In such applications the USB port is transparent: It should just put the requested settings into its serial port. If the DCB requests a setting that the USB driver cannot support then it should return an error code.

Comment: Would it be permissable to just not set the DCB. I know that I need to set the COMMTIMEOUTS struct to get the data I need, but is the DCB similar.

Comment: That can not be answered without documentation or an API specification for the device. Try contacting the supplier.